# Get Facebook/Google access token on Firebase Auth#onAuthStateChanged?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If I authenticate using Auth#signInWithPopup I get a result having credentials.

How can I get the same credentials inside the observer for Auth#onStateChanged?

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the credentials from Auth#onStateChanged. You can only get them from the result of Auth#signInWithPopup or Auth#getRedirectResult. As these fields are only obtained once on sign-in and not maintained or stored by Firebase Auth (eg. OAuth credential, additional IdP data), they are only returned on sign-in completion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage` to cache them after you get it with signInWithPopup.

Answer (score 0):

the User object you get from `onStateChanged` has a method `getIdToken` to get & reset the accessToken if that is what you're looking for.