# Can we get FacebookAccessToken from FirebaseAuth?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

With Flutter, I am able to login with Facebook, and later I want to get the `FacebookAccessToken` because it is needed to correctly get the user `photoURL`.

Is there a way to get the token from `FirebaseAuth`? Or I must store this value in my code?

Login part, we have the access token:

```
FacebookLoginResult result = await new FacebookLogin().logIn(['email', 'public_profile']);
...
FacebookAccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken;
```

Now, let's say in another Widget, we want to get the user `photoURL`

```
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
String url = auth.currentUser.photoURL;
```

This `url` must be appended with `?accessToken=<access_token>` retrieved during the first step. There is a [bug](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3839) created. But for now, can we directly get it from `FirebaseAuth`?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook access token is available from the auth result immediately after the user signs in from the `FacebookAuthCredential` object as [`result.credential.accessToken`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/OAuthCredential/accessToken.html). It is not available from the current user, so if you don't capture immediately after sign-in there's no way to find it later without going back to the Facebook SDK.

Also see:

- [Can I get a facebook access token from firebase.auth().currentUser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336506/can-i-get-a-facebook-access-token-from-firebase-auth-currentuser)
- [How to get provider access token in Firebase functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858683/how-to-get-provider-access-token-in-firebase-functions)
- [Get Facebook/Google access token on Firebase Auth#onAuthStateChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433444/get-facebook-google-access-token-on-firebase-authonauthstatechanged)